# Mouse cursor works for one gif but not the other

Tags: html, css, cursor

I am trying to change my mouse cursor to be a hammer.

I just googled some gif images to see what would happen when i change my css.

The first image works perfectly however my next image doesnt seem to work.

Try it yourself.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" class="test" width="500" height="500">

</canvas>
```

CSS:

```
#myCanvas{
cursor: url(http://www.geniusdv.com/news_and_tutorials/2009/01/05/mouse_locator.gif), default;
}

/*
#myCanvas{
cursor: url(http://www.pjnicholson.com/officexptuts/hammer.gif), default;
}
*/
```

Obviously i replace the comments when changing the image.

Why does it not work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is to big that is why it is not working. Making the image smaller should solve your problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url

Comment: Thank you.. I did not expect that :P

Answer (score 1):

you wrong url image try this

```
#myCanvas{
cursor: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSBgMIeNrWE9XlAxTa3XjonUA0TQsEcz-HFgR39d8TPeLt2vSQLTFb6Ig), default;
}
```

Comment: That is not the same image as mine. but it does work however my url is correct if you paste it into the browser

Comment: yes your image is not, I just showed that it is possible to link the image broken

Comment: Hm okay but it loads in my browser :/

Comment: yes I inserted the image seen in the browser but it does not pick up the canvas for some reason

Comment: search on Google and found your image, the decision is still you keep this image in my folder and ukazyaet path to the saved image

Comment: like this   #myCanvas{
cursor: url(../images/hammer.gif), default;
}